# JavaScript - Define function without calling it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel so so stupid for forgetting this, but I've been out of practice for a minute, and I'm drawing a blank.

Why is slideDown being called onload rather than when the click is handled?

```
function buttonClicked(buttonNumber) {
    $contentBox.slideDown("slow");
};

$button1.click = buttonClicked(1);
```

Comment: Because you are calling `buttonClicked`. The `()` after a function reference always calls the function. Example: `function foo() { alert(42); }; foo();`. Here `foo` is called because I put `()` after the variable name. Btw,  if `$button1` is a jQuery object, then you have to pass a function reference to the `.click` method, not assign a value to it. See http://learn.jquery.com/events/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would want to structure it as

```
$button1.click(function() {
    buttonClicked(1);
});
```

This will make it fire when `$button1` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$button1.click(function() {
    buttonClicked(1);
});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) at api.jquery.com